# aerospike udf -- how lua gets executed? how to run a function only once?

Tags: lua, aerospike

We have a lua script which filters the records , returns the map. I have two questions

1. Does aerospike executes the lua script like an independent script (similar to 'lua ' ) on every query?
2. There is a need to read a file and cache it using a function -- I want this function to be called only once , how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aerospike executes Lua script in a sandboxed environment. The context is reset across calls. So, you cannot read a file and cache values which you can use during next invocation. If you need to pass some information to each call, consider passing them via arguments. Needless to say, its better to not pass huge data structures as arguments. The overhead of encoding/decoding them will be high.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, considering the overhead (if passed as args), it would have been better if there was a provision to cache (like an init method)

Comment: It is a hard design choice to make. i.e if we should preserve state across invocations or not. There is no correct answer. There will be usecases for each of them.